# Too many match points together

Tags: python, opencv, knn, surf

I trying to create a script which given 2 banknote images tells me if the first image appears on the second image. It works ok if the first image appears on the second one but if it isn't, it gives me soemthing like:

[image]

Many many points related to the same point (or very close) in the second image. Do you know a way to filter this?

This is what I do:

```
img1      = cv2.imread(trainImage    , 0)     # trainImage
mask      = cv2.imread(maskTrainImage, 0)     # trainMask
kp1, des1 = surf.detectAndCompute(img1,mask)
kp2, des2 = surf.detectAndCompute(img2, None)

index_params  = dict(algorithm = FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE, trees = 4)
search_params = dict(checks = 50)
flann = cv2.FlannBasedMatcher(index_params, search_params)
matches = flann.knnMatch(des1,des2,k=2)
# store all the good matches as per Lowe's ratio test.
good = []
for m,n in matches:
     if (m.distance < 0.70*n.distance):
        good.append(m)
```

How could I remove all matches in the second image if they are exactly the same point or closer than, lets say 5 px or something like that?